# PowerShell try-catch isn't working

Tags: powershell, try-catch

I'm working on a script and want to check, if a taskname is existing.
It looks so far like this:

```
try {
    Get-ScheduledTaskInfo -TaskName "taskname"
}
catch {
    echo "doesn't exist"
}
```

When I run the code, it prints me the error message and not "doesn't exist":

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> try {
    Get-ScheduledTaskInfo -TaskName "taskname"
}
catch {
    echo "doesn't exist"
}
Get-ScheduledTaskInfo : The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:2 char:5
+     Get-ScheduledTaskInfo -TaskName "taskname"
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (PS_ScheduledTask:Root/Microsoft/...S_ScheduledTask) [Get-ScheduledTaskInfo], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070002,Get-ScheduledTaskInfo
```

Does anybody has an idea why the catch phrase is not triggered?

Thanks for any help!

Best regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`try`/`catch` only catches terminating errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-6):

> Use Try, Catch, and Finally blocks to respond to or handle **terminating errors** in scripts

Use `-ErrorAction Stop` to turn your non-terminating error into a terminating error:

```
Get-ScheduledTaskInfo -TaskName "taskname" -ErrorAction Stop
```

Comment: good idea...i use this to make PS behave like a more traditional language

Answer (score 0):

You can set global variable parameter $ErrorActionPreference to stop (détail : [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/hh847796.aspx)). Not necessary to put -Erroraction on all commands with this method ;)

```
$ErrorActionPreference= "Stop"

try {
    Get-ScheduledTaskInfo -TaskName "taskname"
}
catch {
    echo "doesn't exist"
}
```