# Powershell error message after copy-item with details

Tags: powershell

I'm new to Powershell and currently working on a case need to copy different files to one server. After copy the file to server the result will return to the Log files (successful or fail).

For the failed copy the error message with gives the fail reason such as server is not available or user has no access. The system error message.

I tried to use $errorMessage but it didn't work, could anyone show me how to do it please?

> Blockquote

```
    $dest = "\\server1\folder\as00.LOG"
    $source_path = "\\server2\folder\as00.LOG", "\\server3\folder\as00.LOG  "
    $logProgress = "\\server1\folder\CopyLogs.txt"

    foreach ($Path in $source_path) {    
     If (Test-Path $dest ){
     $i = 1
     While (Test-Path $dest )
     {  $dest = "\\server1\folder\as00$i.LOG"
        $i += 1}
     }else{ New-Item -ItemType File -Path $Dest -Force}

     Copy-Item -Path $Path -Destination $dest -Recurse -Force -errorAction silentlyContinue   
     if($? -eq $false) {
        $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
        echo "Date: $((Get-Date).ToString()). Status: Copy Failure - $ErrorMessage" | out-file -append $logProgress}
     else{
        echo "Date: $((Get-Date).ToString()). Status: Successfully copied" | out-file -append $logProgress}
      }
```

Many thanks!
Lynn

Comment: thank Palle I change image to code

Comment: Super, I upvoted again. Sometimes this downvoting seems alittle harsh, but is all about getting the best possible questions, leading to the best possible answers.

Comment: Use try catch instead of $?. In your catch block u can use `$ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message`. And remove the `-ea silentlycontinue`

Comment: You could add the `$Error[0].exception.message` and then clear the error log at the en with `$Error.clear()`

Comment: @Palle, Again thank you for pointed out. This is my first post I haven't figure out uploaded the code yet. It's good to know the rules and make it easier for help who want to help to read. cheers

Comment: @guiwhatsthat  thank you for your help :) I will try it thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `$ErrorMessage`:

```
$ErrorMessage = $Error[0].Exception.Message    # probably
$ErrorMessage = $Error[0].ErrorDetails.Message # less likely
```

For `if($?`, I recommend using the standard `Try`/`Catch`. `-ErrorAction Stop` is required [because](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48707183/5039142)

```
try{
    Copy-Item -Path $Path -Destination $dest -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction Stop

    # if the script gets to this part, Copy-Item did not error
    echo "Date: $((Get-Date).ToString()). Status: Successfully copied" | out-file -append $logProgress
}catch{
    # what to do if an error is encountered:
    $ErrorMessage = $Error[0].Exception.Message
    echo "Date: $((Get-Date).ToString()). Status: Copy Failure - $ErrorMessage" | out-file -append $logProgress}
}
```

<sub>**Related:** [How to capture and print PowerShell exception message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38421525/5039142)</sub>